# Fuzzy 'Countif' excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have reports I'm running for learning outcomes for students, tagged as `AAA 123 - CLO 1 - 7.17.17` for example.

The dataset I import will have variations on that string, keeping constant however, the `CLO 1`, `CLO 2` etc (as these are the numbered CLOs for a particular course.

I have a countif formula setup, but it only works if update the formulas each time to reflect the new string ie changing `AAA 123 - CLO 1 - 7.17.17` to `BBB 345- CLO 1 - 7.18.17` for example.

My question is, can I write a formula to just parse the `CLO 1` part of the string as those characters are always present?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "*CLO 1*")
```

should do it